# search by date mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, search

I have a table named  `messages`:

```
date (format DATETIME)
id
text
user_id(FK)
```

and a table named `users`:

```
id
name
```

how to get count of messages with given date (`message date = xxxx-xx-xx`) for each user? 
like:

```
 user       message_count
 user1_name      5
 user2_name      2
```

and how get users with 3 or more message today?

```
SELECT users.name 
FROM users 
WHERE Users.id IN ( SELECT Messages.user_id 
                    FROM chat.Messages 
                    GROUP BY Messages.user_id 
                    HAVING COUNT(*) >=3
                  )
```

It returns users who have 3 or more messages, how to get users, who have 3 or more message today? `where date = now()`

Comment: This line **and users with 3 or more message today** confused me about your expected output. Please explain this too.

Comment: i'm sorry, its second query

Comment: SELECT users.name FROM users WHERE Users.id IN (SELECT        Messages.user_id FROM chat.Messages GROUP BY Messages.user_id HAVING COUNT(*) >=3) 

its return users with 3 or more message, how get users with 3 or message, where date = now() ?

Comment: So you need two separate queries?

Comment: yes, its 2 queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to get count of messages with given date (message date = xxxx-xx-xx) for each user?

**Query #1:**

```
SELECT 
users.name,
COUNT(*) message_count
FROM messages 
INNER JOIN users ON messages.user_id = users.id
WHERE messages.date = PUT_YOUR_DATE_HERE
GROUP BY messages.user_id;
```

How to get count of messages for those users who have 3 or more messages today?

**Query #2:**

```
SELECT 
users.name,
COUNT(*) message_count
FROM messages 
INNER JOIN users ON messages.user_id = users.id
WHERE messages.date = CURDATE()
GROUP BY messages.user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.name,count(*) from messages a,users b where date ='2016-05-28' group by b.name
```

Comment: It would be better if you added some description as to why the query solves the OP's issue. @karpengold: "it didn't work" is also not very good. At least add the MySQL error message in the comment so you can help who's helping you.

Comment: An answer like this could be more helpful if you could add some more explanation of the code you've provided.